# Parse JSON with no quotes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I get some JSON response that I want to parse and display on screen. The problem is that it comes sometimes with no quote around some of the string values. For example:  `reference":D578699A, "success":1, "error_code":0, "error_text":"Success" }` It might have "" for some of the strings. How should I handle this situation? Many Thanks!

Comment: If your server is passing you malformed JSON, you should update it to pass correctly formed data. That is the real answer here. You should fix the server that is giving you this bad data. However, I suppose it is possible to fix this with code. However, it would be a bandaid to the real problem. If you can't call `JSON.parse` on a string to make it a JSON object, then you should fix the server that gave you the string. IMO.

Comment: ^ this. Don't slap duct tape on the problem to fix it, fix it the right way.

Comment: it have something to do with your server not in your javscript
also server would never generate that kind of json result, I mean a string without a double quote

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the best answer is fix the buggy code in the service that does it.

So if you will not be able to use JSON.parse you can go old school and use eval or new Function.

```
var x = '{foo:"bar", "cat" : "dog"}';
eval("var o =" + x);
console.log(o);
```

or

```
var x = '{foo:"bar", "cat" : "dog"}';
var o = new Function("return " + x)();
console.log(o)
```

Use of these solutions opens you up to XSS attacks..

Another option is write a regular expression that tries to fix it

Answer (score 2):

**Some observations :**

- `JSON` coming from the server is not a valid `JSON` as it is having a string value without quotes(").

[image]

This issue should be corrected from server side only. So, that you will get the valid `JSON` in response like below.

[image]