# How to convert a malformed json string into an object?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a string which pretty much looks like an object like below

```
{table:restaurants,col:name,col_val:tacos}
```

As you can see it pretty much looks like an object but it is not. So obviously functions like `JSON.parse()` fails. Is there any way I can turn this into an object and work on?

**Note:** I am getting the data from another source and hence I have no control over the format of data I recieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing unquoted JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51430762/parsing-unquoted-json-string) and [Parse JSON with no quotes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42987868) and [Parsing “relaxed” JSON without eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637517)

Comment: Depending on the possible strings, `JSON.parse( str.replace( '{', '{"' ).replace( '}', '"}' ).replace( /([:,])/g, '"$1"') )` may be sufficient. Pretty fragile code though.

Comment: @Paulpro I really like your one liner answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here, this creates an object.

```js
let obj = {};
let incoming = "{table:restaurants,col:name,col_val:tacos}"
                              .replace("{","")
                              .replace("}","")
                              .split(',')
                              .map(e => [e.split(':')[0],e.split(':')[1]])
                              .forEach(e => {
                                obj[e[0]] = e[1];
                              });

console.log(obj);
```